# How do I get my card to flip back over (Stanford 193p)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

So, I tried to finish assignment one for the Stanford 193P iOS 7 course and create a randomized card flip, with different ranks and suits. I modified the code to where I think it will be facing down and face up to display a random card for each card flip, until all cards in the deck are used up. However, now the it won't turn over (stays facedown). When the app starts with the card values (i.e. suit) displayed, I get a storyboard error (when clicked, it opens my storyboard window). What am I doing wrong?

Here is the coding in my ViewController.m file I used for the card (as a button) to perform actions once clicked:

```
- (IBAction)touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender
```

{

```
if ([sender.currentTitle length])
{
    [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardfront"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    CGCard *randomCard = [self.fullDeck drawRandomCard];
    if (randomCard)
    {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cardback"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:randomCard.contents forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
self.flipCount++;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The reason its not flipping back over is probably because your

```
 randomCard.contents
```

is nil.

Since I dont have those images I cant use your code, but here is some sample code to change the background color of the button

```
- (IBAction) touchCardButton:(UIButton *)sender
{

if ([sender.currentTitle length])
{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
    [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [sender setTitle:@"1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}

}
```

make sure your randomCard.contents is not nil and that should fix your issue